# Solr TermFreq with conditional Filterquery

Tags: c#, solr, solr-query-syntax

Hi Im trying to build a query in c# using solr:

```
Query.Append($"&fq={{frange l=3}}termfreq(Description,'keyword') OR {{frange l=1}}termfreq(title, 'keyword'")"
```

While this one below works :

```
Query.Append($"&fq={{frange l=3}}termfreq(Description,'keyword')")
```

The occurrence should be 3 times in the description OR 1 time in title.
But executing the query gives a syntax error. Using termfreq once works but with conditions, it's failing.

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: There's quite a few things going on here; you have duplicate `{{`'s (one set should be enough) and you have placed the `OR` inside the `termfreq` function call; you also say that they should be three times in the description _and_ one time in the title, but you use `OR` in your query. Possible solutions will depend on exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response MatsLindh. I have updated the query and also the description. {{}} I have used this as an escape character for {}

Comment: I'm guessing you can do this by collapsing it into one single frange: `{!frange l=3}add(termfreq(Description,'keyword'),mul(termfreq(Title,'keyword'), 3))` - since that would give you 3 as a value if it's three times in Description, or if its at least once in Title.

Comment: The query returns results that also include docs that don't have the keyword.

Comment: Hi Mats, please do the honour of posting this as the answer. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by collapsing it into one single frange:

```
{!frange l=3}add(termfreq(Description,'keyword'),mul(termfreq(Title,'keyword'), 3))
```

This will give you 3 as a value if it's three times in Description, or if it's at least once in Title (being the sum of occurences of `keyword` in Description and occurences of `keyword` in Title - multiplied by three. So if it occurs once in the title, you get `1 * 3 => 3`, but for the description field you don't multiply at all - meaning you'll have to have it occur three times to get to three.